# My ubuntu 12 .04 will not update

Tags: upgrade, updates, update-manager

Hi I'm having problems updating my Ubuntu 12.04, when I type `sudo apt-get update` I get this

```
howie@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for howie: 
Get:1 http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg [198 B]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                               
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                     
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg [316 B]           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release                                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release                 
Ign http://dl.google.com stable Release                               
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex         
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex          
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release [11.9 kB]
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages                      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main amd64 Packages   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe amd64 Packages         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse amd64 Packages       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main amd64 Packages     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex
Get:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources [29.5 kB]
Get:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages [18.6 kB]
Get:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages [18.6 kB]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Fetched 79.1 kB in 3s (22.4 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A040830F7FAC5991
howie@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgail-3-0 : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (= 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.6) but 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.8 is installed
 libgtk-3-bin : Depends: libgtk-3-common (= 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.6) but 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.8 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
howie@ubuntu:~$ apt-get -f install
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
howie@ubuntu:~$
```

I also have a red dot with a white line across it in the top right screen.
I am not very good on computers so any  would be much appreciated as I want to upgrade to the newest version.

i get this

```
howie@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
[sudo] password for howie: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libkrb5-3:i386 libgconf-2-4:i386 libatk1.0-0:i386 libk5crypto3:i386
  libstdc++6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxcomposite1:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386
  libroken18-heimdal:i386 libidn11:i386 libnss3:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386
  libjpeg8:i386 linux-headers-3.2.0-35 libdbus-glib-1-2:i386
  libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libnspr4-0d:i386 libcairo2:i386 libgnutls26:i386
  libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 libtasn1-3:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libexpat1:i386
  libdatrie1:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386 libgconf2-4:i386
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libxcb1:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libwind0-heimdal:i386
  libxau6:i386 libpixman-1-0:i386 libcups2:i386 libcurl3:i386
  libxinerama1:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 gir1.2-unique-3.0 libxft2:i386
  libxdmcp6:i386 libgcrypt11:i386 linux-headers-3.2.0-35-generic libthai0:i386
  libkeyutils1:i386 libasound2:i386 libxrender1:i386 libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386
  libnspr4:i386 libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libxss1:i386 libheimbase1-heimdal:i386
  libtiff4:i386 libjasper1:i386 libudev0:i386 libavahi-client3:i386
  libx11-6:i386 libsasl2-2:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libpango1.0-0:i386
  libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxcb-render0:i386 librtmp0:i386
  libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libxi6:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxcb-shm0:i386
  libxext6:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386 libavahi-common3:i386 libxrandr2:i386
  libnss3-1d:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386
  libssl1.0.0:i386 libgpg-error0:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libgail-3-0 libgtk-3-bin
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libgail-3-0 libgtk-3-bin
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 202 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/39.9 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgail-3-0:
 libgail-3-0 depends on libgtk-3-0 (= 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.6); however:
  Version of libgtk-3-0 on system is 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.8.
dpkg: error processing libgail-3-0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgtk-3-bin:
 libgtk-3-bin depends on libgtk-3-common (= 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.6); however:
  Version of libgtk-3-common on system is 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.8.
dpkg: error processing libgtk-3-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgail-3-0
 libgtk-3-bin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
howie@ubuntu:~$ apt-get install -f with sudo: sudo apt-get install -f
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
howie@ubuntu:~$ apt-get install -f with sudo: sudo apt-get install -f
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
howie@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libkrb5-3:i386 libgconf-2-4:i386 libatk1.0-0:i386 libk5crypto3:i386
  libstdc++6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxcomposite1:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386
  libroken18-heimdal:i386 libidn11:i386 libnss3:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386
  libjpeg8:i386 linux-headers-3.2.0-35 libdbus-glib-1-2:i386
  libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libnspr4-0d:i386 libcairo2:i386 libgnutls26:i386
  libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 libtasn1-3:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libexpat1:i386
  libdatrie1:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386 libgconf2-4:i386
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libxcb1:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libwind0-heimdal:i386
  libxau6:i386 libpixman-1-0:i386 libcups2:i386 libcurl3:i386
  libxinerama1:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 gir1.2-unique-3.0 libxft2:i386
  libxdmcp6:i386 libgcrypt11:i386 linux-headers-3.2.0-35-generic libthai0:i386
  libkeyutils1:i386 libasound2:i386 libxrender1:i386 libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386
  libnspr4:i386 libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libxss1:i386 libheimbase1-heimdal:i386
  libtiff4:i386 libjasper1:i386 libudev0:i386 libavahi-client3:i386
  libx11-6:i386 libsasl2-2:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libpango1.0-0:i386
  libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxcb-render0:i386 librtmp0:i386
  libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libxi6:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxcb-shm0:i386
  libxext6:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386 libavahi-common3:i386 libxrandr2:i386
  libnss3-1d:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386
  libssl1.0.0:i386 libgpg-error0:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libgail-3-0 libgtk-3-bin
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libgail-3-0 libgtk-3-bin
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 202 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/39.9 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgail-3-0:
 libgail-3-0 depends on libgtk-3-0 (= 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.6); however:
  Version of libgtk-3-0 on system is 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.8.
dpkg: error processing libgail-3-0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgtk-3-bin:
 libgtk-3-bin depends on libgtk-3-common (= 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.6); however:
  Version of libgtk-3-common on system is 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.8.
dpkg: error processing libgtk-3-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgail-3-0
 libgtk-3-bin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: post the output of `sudo apt-get install -f` on your question.

Comment: You need to run `apt-get install -f` with `sudo`: `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Comment: i did that i got this response

Comment: No, you ran it without `sudo`. Run `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Comment: tk-3-bin:
 libgtk-3-bin depends on libgtk-3-common (= 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.6); however:
  Version of libgtk-3-common on system is 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.8.
dpkg: error processing libgtk-3-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgail-3-0
 libgtk-3-bin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
howie@ubuntu:~$

Comment: libgail-3-0
 libgtk-3-bin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: post the full error report on your question by click [this](http://askubuntu.com/posts/448158/edit)

Comment: i just edited my question with what i response i got , hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

First run the below commands to remove all the unused packages,

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then hold the packages (`libgail-3-0`, `libgtk-3-bin`) from being upgraded,

```
sudo apt-mark hold libgail-3-0
sudo apt-mark hold libgtk-3-bin
```

Now you won't get any error after running `sudo apt-get install -f` command.

Comment: yeah it seems to be working it is removing a lot of the packages

Comment: do i now type in sudo get apt updates

Comment: Now run `sudo apt-get upgrade` command.I think it shows nothing.

Comment: yes its updating thanks very much   Avinash Raj i will accept yor answer now